# NUXT SSL NGINX config PM2 | NUXT site doesn't update

Tags: nginx, ssl, nuxt.js, pipeline, pm2

I'm running a Vue/NUXT site with PM2 on NGINX with SSL. When I run "npm run build" on the production server, the live site doesn’t update on my changes. Some cache issue maybe?? Or is my pipeline wrong? Please find my whole NGINX config and pipeline commands below. All is running on an Ubuntu 20.04 server with NodeJS Express. NUXT 2.14.7

```
#server { # listen 80;
# server_name example.com www.example.com test.example.com;
# HTTP to HTTPS redirections for all the subdomains
# return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
#}
server {
server_name www.example.com;
# ssl_* directives here
# www to non-www for SEO canonical reasons
return 301 http://example.com$request_uri;

    listen 443 ssl http2; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
server_name example.com;
# ssl_* directives here
location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3001;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
##root /var/www/example.com/html;
index index.html index.php index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
# PHP
##location ~ \.php$ {
##include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
##fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
##}
location = /favicon.ico {
log_not_found off; access_log off;
}
location = /robots.txt {
log_not_found off; access_log off; allow all;
}
location ~* \.((ico|css|js|gif|jpeg|jpg|png|woff|ttf|otf|svg|woff2|webp))$ {
expires 24h;
add_header Cache-Control private;
}
# (For WordPress permalinks)
#location / {
#try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
#}

    listen 443 ssl http2; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
server_name test.example.com;
# ssl_* directives here
root /var/www/example.com/test;
index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
# PHP
location ~ \.php$ {
include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
} location = /favicon.ico {
log_not_found off; access_log off;
} location = /robots.txt {
log_not_found off; access_log off; allow all;
}
location ~* \.((ico|css|js|gif|jpeg|jpg|png|woff|ttf|otf|svg|woff2|webp))$ {
expires 24h;
add_header Cache-Control private;
}
# (For WordPress permalinks)
location / {
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

} 

server {
    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


listen 80;
server_name example.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
server {
    if ($host = test.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


listen 80;
server_name test.example.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

I update the site on the production server with a pipeline to Bitbucket:

```
# I run ./deployApi.sh on the production server with below content:
root="/var/www/example.com/html"
cd $root
echo -e '\e[1m\e[34mPulling code from remote..\e[0m\n'
git pull https://exampleuser@bitbucket.org/exampleproject/examplerepo.git
echo -e '\e[1m\e[34m\nInstalling required packages..\e[0m\n'
npm run build
echo -e '\e[1m\e[34m\nRestarting service..\e[0m\n'
# Replace 1 with the ID of the service running your application
pm2 start -- --port 3001
echo -e '\n\e[1m\e[34mDeployment successful\e[0m'
```

Comment: There is quite a few things here. Could you somehow try to narrow this one down. By trying to debug if it's a Nuxt app or a Nginx issue, by hosting it on Heroku or alike?

Comment: @kissu I hosted it at Vercel before without issues, so it's either my NGINX file above or my Bitbucket pipeline deploy above which goes wrong.